# Request refund from booking website or airline?

Tags: international-travel, bookings, airlines, refunds, american-airlines

I booked a flight through Travelocity, and the flight was changed by more than 24 hours. Should I request a refund from Travelocity, or from American Airlines?

I'm a US citizen flying from China.

Answer (score 2):

You should request a refund from Travelocity.
Airlines may not be able to help you here.
Although the airline may offer full refund, there may be change/cancellation charges by Travelocity.

Comment: In support of this answer, there are reasons why the airline may not be able to deal with you at all - depending on the agreement between Travelocity and American Airlines, you might not be American Airlines customer at all, you might be owned by Travelocity and AA might not be able to do anything with your booking without Travelocity initiating that change.  It depends on whether the agreement between the two is one of agent, reseller etc.  So, deal with Travelocity in the first instance, only try AA if that fails, and if AA cant do anything then consider a chargeback on your credit card.